# How to display a list across multiple sites?

Tags: list, bcs, content-query-web-part

I want to be able to create a customized list, "Test", on my main page, "Home" of SharePoint.

I want to be able to link to that custom list, "Test", onto another site in the same collection, "Clients".

The most information I've found is on this site right here https://stackoverflow.com/a/418117, but I'm not sure where I can get more information on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "link to that custom list"?

Comment: I guess I mean how do I take that List and show the same list on another site.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are couple of ways.

- You could use SharePoint Designer and insert a DataView Web Part. This may well be the best idea; it looks a lot like a normal List view.
- You could use the Content Query Web Part to display items from that 'Test' list. You'll need to be using standard/enterprise edition SharePoint (i.e. not Foundation), and turn on the Publishing Infrastructure Site Collection feature to make that web part (amongst doing lots of other things) available. You'll also need to configure it to show the data you want as you want it. It's probably not as simple as the DataView web part if you want control over the exact appearance.

That's without going down the route of custom code, etc..